# detect partial strings and rearrange a csv accordingly

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I am very-very new to Python and still learning my way around. I am trying to process some data and I have a very big raw_data.csv file that reads as follows:

```
ARB1,k_abc,t_def,s_ghi,1.321
ARB2,ref,k_jkl,t_mno,s_pqr,0.31
ARB3,k_jkl,t_mno,s_pqr,qrs,0.132
ARB4,sql,k_jkl,t_mno,s_pqr,ets,0.023
```

I want to append this data in an existing all_data.csv and it should look like

```
ARB1,k_abc,t_def,s_ghi,1.321
ARB2,k_jkl,t_mno,s_pqr,0.31
ARB3,k_jkl,t_mno,s_pqr,0.132
ARB4,k_jkl,t_mno,s_pqr,0.023
```

As you can see, the code has to detect partial strings and numbers and rearrange them in an orderly way (by excluding the cells that don't have them). I was trying to use the csv module with very little luck. Can anyone help please?

Comment: It appears you need to exclude 3 character lowercase letter strings, like `"ref", "qrs", "sql", "ets"`. You can extract these with the regex module, such as `re.findall(',([a-z][a-z][a-z],)', data)` and then replace them in the data with an empty string.

Comment: That’s the problem. The names of these strings aren’t fixed (I just gave a few examples) change and the file is huge to deal with. I think rather than exclusion, I need a selection strategy for k_, t_ and s_ partial strings.

Answer (score 0):

You can parse this using [pandas.read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) on Pandas. Alternatively, if you don't want to use Pandas, I would recommend simply reading in data, a line at a time and splitting by commas using [Python's string operators](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html). You can create a 2-D array that you can populate row-by-row as you read in more data.